# Search a specific value in a array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

Hi have a array saved in the variable `$someArray`. This is the content of `$someArray`:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [CityDesc] => Burgbretzingen 
        [CityId] => 63910 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [CityDesc] => Bühlerzimmern 
        [CityId] => 1288010 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [CityDesc] => Einkorn 
        [CityId] => 320610 
    ) 
    [3] => Array 
        ( 
        [CityDesc] => Scherbenmühle 
        [CityId] => 711910 
        )
    [4] => Array ( 
        [CityDesc] => Schwäbisch Hall 
        [CityId] => 1694510 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [CityDesc] => Traubenmühle 
        [CityId] => 493610 
    )
)
```

I will readout the this value `63910` (the [CityId]) if I search for `"Burgbretzingen"`.

Comment: Here's an elegant solution: https://3v4l.org/7uH90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach it by using `array_column`

```
$res = array_column($a, 'CityId', 'CityDesc');
echo empty($res['Burgbretzingen']) ? '' : $res['Burgbretzingen'];
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/s1TNk